# Jsfiddle {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

Estou testando este código no JSFiddle e tenho como resposta:

> {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Aqui esto código [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexjosesilva/ryR3N/)

Segui abaixo o código:

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="../lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>     
<body>      
    <div id="mensagens" class="classErro"></div>    
    <div>           
        <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    <label for="rd-sexo">Tipo Vinculo</label><br>
                    <label>Titular</label><input id="tvinculo" type="radio" name="tvinculo" value="1" /><br>
                    <label>Dependente</label><input id="tvinculo" type="radio" name="tvinculo" value="2" />

                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="name">Nome Beneficiario: </label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" >
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
                    <input id="cpf" type="cpf" name="cpf">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="nmat">Numero Matricula:</label>
                    <input id="nmat" name="nmat" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

**Na parte JS**

```
/* Sucesso ao validar*/
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    }
});
/* Regras de negocios*/
$().ready(function() {
    $("#commentForm").validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 20
                },
                cpf:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 11
                },
                nmat:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 11
                },
                tvinculo:{
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "Por favor preencha o campo Nome <br>",
                    minlength: "O campo Nome minimo de caracteres  20 <br>"
                },
                cpf: {
                    required: "Por favor preencha o campo CPF<br>",
                    minlength: "O campo CPF minimo de caracteres  11 <br>"
                },
                nmat: {
                    required: "Por favor preencha o campo Matricula<br>",
                    minlength: "O campo Matricula minimo de caracteres  20 <br>"
                },
                tvinculo:{
                    required: "Por favor preencha o campo Tipo de Vinculo<br>"
                }
            },
            //Monta a mensagem em uma caixa separada
            errorLabelContainer: $('#mensagens')
    });
});
```

**Na parte CSS**

```
    form.cmxform label.error{
        color: red;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    .classErro{color: red; font-style: italic;}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta é que você não pode colocar todas as tags HTML igual está na sua Demo (só coloque as tags que estão entre as `<body>` e `</body>`). Então eu criei o mesmo de maneira correta adicionando o elementos [JQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js), [JQuery.Validation](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js) e [additional-methods](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js) na guia External Resources e configurando todas as partes para que funcione corretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Exemplo:*** [**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nBky8/).